# Firebase Crash Reporting, disable reports for debug builds

Tags: android, firebase-console

We are doing the beta-test of our android app this time. Is there any way to stop android emulators from sending crash reports to the Firebase Console? 
First we have to look at the devices of each problem to manually close them because we don't see if the problem comes from developing/testing or from a beta-tester.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your custom `Application` class `onCreate` method:

```
FirebaseCrash.setCrashCollectionEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG);
```

If you compile the debug APK for emulators you are fine

Answer (score 1):

You can add a meta-data entry to the AndroidManifest.xml for your app to disable Crash Reporting at build time.

`<meta-data android:name="firebase_crash_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />`

Or you can disable by adding in `Application` or `MainActivity`,

```
FirebaseCrash.setCrashCollectionEnabled(false);
```

For more info check this link,
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/disable-sdk